# Optimizing ONNX model using huggingface optimu, knowing only the base model on which this ONNX is finetuned

Tags: deep-learning, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, onnx, quantization

I have an ONNX model, saved as:

```
onnx_path = "/local/model.onnx"
```

The model was downloaded from huggingface (microsoft/dit-base-finetuned-rvlcdip) and finetuned on custom dataset.

Since dit is a bert-like model, I tried to optimize it using the following:

```
optimized_model = optimize_model(input=onnx_path, model_type="bert", use_gpu=False)
```

However, when running inference the difference with respect to execution time is the same as before, only the size of the model is reduced. Is there another way to optimize custom models?

All the available documentations for optimization with optimum assume that the model is uploaded on huggingface hub.